# JavaScript сортировка работает некорректно

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть массив в котором содержатся объекты `Ключ и значени`е ));

```
var allObject=[
      { title: 'Marker 1', latLng: 14 },
        { title: 'Marker 2', latLng:15  },
        { title: 'Marker 3', latLng: 1 },
        { title: 'Marker 4', latLng:42 },
        { title: 'Marker 5', latLng:2},
        { title: 'Marker 6', latLng: 5}   
];
```

Хочу сортировать чтоб 1 шло минимальное значение. От минимума к максимуму

```
allObject.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.latLng > b.latLng) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.latLng < b.latLng) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a должно быть равным b
  return 0;
});
```

Да и объектов там может быть около 50 или более. Мой метод сортировки работает некорректно: порой дает не то, что есть. Путает местами как сортировать массив с объектами от минимума к максимуму. Был бы благодарен, во врес сортировки сталкивался с тем, что он 6 дает после 14, или 8 после 32... Как это понять? и как правильно отсортировать?

Comment: на представленном примере код отлично работает. Возможно ты меняешь значения уже после сортировки?

Comment: @Grundy да но неужели вы не сталкивались с тем что я сказал ?

Comment: У вас там в `latLng` точно везде числа, а не строки?

Comment: нет. все работает именно так как и задумывалось

Comment: Ну отладчик же изобрели мудрые люди. Ну поставьте вы breakpoint внутри функции-компаратора, посмотрите что и как он сравнивает и сами всё поймете, господа, если по каждому такому вопросу бежать на SO вы не научитесь программированию.

Comment: @iksuy вам надо еще тоже самое [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/655659/191482)  написать :)