# Галерея на чистом js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят проблема не знаю в чем написал код для галереи , вроде все правильно но ничего не выходит даже ошибку не выдает в консоле

```js
function closeModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function showModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
(function() {
  var thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery_img'), //target thumbnail images,
    imageMain = document.querySelector('.imageMain'); //target main image
  var leftArrow = document.querySelector('.arrowleft'),
    rightArrow = document.querySelector('.arrowright');
  var currentIndex = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      imageMain.src = evt.target.src.replace('150/100', '1000/400');
      currentIndex = evt.target.id.substr(6, evt.target.id.length) - 1;
    });
  }
  leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      currentIndex--;
      imageMain.src = thumbnails[currentIndex].src.replace('150/100', '1000/400');
    }
  });

  rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (currentIndex < thumbnails.length - 1) {
      currentIndex++;
      imageMain.src = thumbnails[currentIndex].src.replace('150/100', '1000/400');
    }
  });


})();
```

```css
.Window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window>div {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 640px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 74px -50px;
  background-size: 925px 640px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  right-12px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 992px;
}

.fbshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 509px;
  left: 992px;
}

.twshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 546px;
  left: 992px;
}

a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.leftcol {
  width: 200px;
  height: 590px;
  float: left;
  background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.rigcol {
  width: 45px;
  height: 590px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 50px;
}

.learn {
  position: relative;
  top: -58px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0066cc;
  float: right;
}

.learnT {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.learn:hover {
  background: #3399FF;
}

.learn:hover a {
  color: #fff
}

hr {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 462px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

.Tfind {
  margin-top: 380px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.Thorizont {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 211px;
  color: white;
}

.hr2 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

.hr3 {
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 226px;
  left: 5px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 86px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.img2 {
  margin-top: 89px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.bgmain {
  width: 785px;
  height: 443px;
  margin-top: 107px;
}

.button1 {
  width: 732px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 135px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.nav {
  font: 12pt;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.2);
}

.img3 {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.arrowleft {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: 205px;
  width: 3%;
  float: left;
}

.arrowright {
  position: relative;
  top: 205px;
  right: 45px;
  width: 3%;
  float: right;
}

.arrowleft img {
  width: 100%;
}

.arrowright img {
  width: 100%;
}

.arrowleft img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 95%;
}

.arrowleft img:active {
  width: 85%;
}

.arrowright img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 95%;
}

.arrowright img:active {
  width: 85%;
}

.galleryWrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.imageMain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}

.imageMain img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.thumbWrapper {
  margin-top: 405px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.thumbmails {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 37px;
  padding-left: 190px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1.85s;
}

.thumbmails li {
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#ModalOpen" title="">
  <button type="button" class="button1" id="modal_close" onclick="showModal();">
        <img src="images/ban.jpg">
    </button>
</a>
<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="galleryWrapper">
      <div class="imageMain">
        <img src="images/fullsize/1.jpg" class="imageMain" />
      </div>
      <div class="arrowleft"><img src="images/left.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="arrowright"><img src="images/right.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="thumbWrapper">
        <ul class="thumbmails">
          <li><img id="thumb-1" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-2" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-3" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-4" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-5" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-6" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-7" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-8" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-9" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-10" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-11" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/11.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-12" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-13" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/13.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img id="thumb-14" class="gallery_img" src="images/thumbs/14.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftcol">
      <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
      <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
      <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#tab1" class="active">Video</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#tab2">Horizon Zero Dawn</a>
            </br>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#tab3">Through Aloy's Eyes</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-1">

      </div>
      <div id="tab-2">

      </div>
      <div id="tab-3">

      </div>

      <img src="images/esrb.jpg" class="img3" />

    </div>
    <div class="rigcol">
      <button type="button" class="button2" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">
                <img src="images/x.jpg">
            </button>
      <button type="button" class="button3">
                <img src="images/share.jpg">
            </button>
      <hr>
      <p class="Tfind"> Find <br/>US ON</p>
      </hr>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fbshare">
        <img src="images/fb.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="twshare">
        <img src="images/twit.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <img src="images/i.jpg" class="img1">
      <hr class="hr2">
      <p class="Thorizont">Click on Horizon Zero Dawn to see the next era of mankind</p>
      <div class="learn">
        <p class="learnT"><a href="#learnmore">Learn More <strong> > </strong></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется проще всего вам открыть debugger и пройтись в нем, наблюдая что где происходит..... в ином случае получается, что вы просите кого-то с SO сделать ровно такие же аналогичные действия.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский debugger не находит эту ошибку

Comment: Что значит "всё правильно но ничего не выходит даже ошибку не выдает"? Если всё правильно, значит вы бы не создали этот вопрос. Ошибка в консоли - это значит что у вас какая-то техническая ошибка была бы (обращение к undefined например, несоответствия типов и т.п.). В данном случае у вас ошибка логики. Что вы именно хотели сделать мы не знаем. Опишите подробнее, что именно не работает, на каком этапе. Отладчик автоматически ошибки не находит, это должны делать вы с его помощью.

Comment: @iksuy нужно чтобы при нажатиии на left или right arrow должна меняться картинка и при нажатии на thumbs миниатюры должна появляться эта же картинка